# How to measure response time with Swift Moya?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, moya

As i know on Alamofire, we have timeline object where we can extract the response time.
However, how do i get the response time from a Moya Request?

```
public final class Response: CustomDebugStringConvertible, Equatable {

    /// The status code of the response.
    public let statusCode: Int

    /// The response data.
    public let data: Data

    /// The original URLRequest for the response.
    public let request: URLRequest?

    /// The HTTPURLResponse object.
    public let response: HTTPURLResponse? //this does not return response time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Session with a ClosureEventMonitor.

```
class MoyaConfig {

    static let monitor: ClosureEventMonitor = {
        let monitor = ClosureEventMonitor()
        monitor.taskDidFinishCollectingMetrics = { _, task, metrics in
            // do something with the metrics (URLSessionTaskMetrics)
        }
        return monitor
    }()

    static let apiSession: Session = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = Session(configuration: configuration, startRequestsImmediately: false, eventMonitors: [monitor])
        return session
    }()
}
let api = MoyaProvider<API>(session: MoyaConfig.apiSession)
```

https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/2073#issuecomment-737126499